# Does metric on a vector space form a topologycal vector space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space and that on $X$ there exists a metric $d$. Denote $\tau$ be the topology induce by metric $d$. Do we can conclude that $(X,\tau)$ is a topological vector space? I know that we need to prove that two operators $+$ and $\cdot$ are continuous, but I don't know how to prove!

Thanks!

Comment: The metric can be completely unrelated to the linear structure. So $(X,\tau)$ has no reason for being a tvs. For example, consider the discrete metric $d$.

Comment: @Etienne: I agree with you in spirit, but with the discrete metric the operators $+$ and $\cdot$ are automatically continuous. If that's all you need to be a topological vector space, then the discrete metric isn't a counterexample.

Comment: @froggie It is a counterexample: scalar multiplication is not continuous.

Comment: @Etienne: Ahh, yes, of course you are right!

Comment: Anyone can help me why $l^p$, $0<p<1$ is a tvs?

Comment: @Richkent Because $$d_p(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert x_n-y_n\rvert^p$$ is a particularly nice metric. It is translation-invariant ($d_p(x,y) = d_p(x+z,y+z)$ for all $x,y,z$), and that gives you the continuity of addition. And you have $d_p(c\cdot x,0) = \lvert c\rvert^p d_p(x,0)$, from which you can obtain the continuity of scalar multiplication.